# Keeping symbols from different builds of static libraries separate

Tags: c++, ios, linker, static-libraries, static-linking

I have an static Objective-C++ library **basic.a**, with a function `BasicFunction()`. Static Objective-C++ libraries **foo.a** and **bar.a** depend on **basic.a** and have functions `Foo()` and `Bar()` that call `BasicFunction()`.

Here's the tricky part: When I make a project that links in **foo.a** and **bar.a**, each built at a different time, I want `Foo()` to call the version of `BasicFunction()` that was there when it was built, and `Bar()` to call the version of `BasicFunction()` that was there when it was built. (This is so that newer libraries will not link in an old `BasicFunction()` that is missing bug fixes.)

What's happening now is that `Foo()` and `Bar()` both call the same version of `BasicFunction()`, the one that is in whichever of the two **foo.a** and **bar.a** that is linked first in the project. Changing symbol visibility does not seem to work because if `BasicFunction()` is hidden, it's hidden in **basic.a** and can't be seen by **foo.a** or **bar.a**.

If there is no good way to make the libraries call different versions of `BasicFunction()`, how can I at least detect the problem? I've tried a sentinel class that looks to make sure it only gets initialized once, but the linker seems to optimize the two sentinels in different builds of **basic.a** into just one, again from whichever library that is linked first.

Comment: If `BasicFunction` is *supposed* to be the same function at all times, refactor the code and link against `foo.a bar.a basic.a`. If `foo.a` and `bar.a` require different implementations of the basic function, give it different names.

Comment: I've simplified the story a little bit - the problem is that libraries distributed several months later are using a version of BasicFunction() that is missing bug fixes.

Comment: @Luke: Hmm, I guess I don't really understand how you can have _statically_ linked libraries but still can't control the linking process... can't you just relink everything with the new, bugfixed version?

Comment: We can, we just don't want to have to redistribute bar.a to a client when we give them foo.a. They should be able to link in foo.a without having to worry about it calling old code.

Comment: This is the way linkers have worked since the dawn of time. It's up to you to make sure foo.a and bar.a can use the same version of `BasicFunction`, and that the proper version of basic.a is linked.

Comment: @Luke: If bar.a doesn't actual contain a copy of `BasicFunction`, then you should be fine, if you're in a position to distribute `basic.a` (as you should, given that it contains a bugfix). If for some reason you've already copied `BasicFunction` into bar.a, then indeed you have multiple versions of it -- not sure what to do, but I guess that's what you get for shipping multiple copies of the same code (in bar.a and foo.a). If the user requires both, why have `BasicFunction` in both?

Comment: We're not shipping the same code, just libraries that link in the same functions. Also, we don't distribute basic.a, just bar.a and foo.a, which depend on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's unlikely anyone else will have this particular problem, but the solution was to have an Objective-C sentinel class called from a plain C function, both with unique names per build, called by each library. The sentinel class ensures there is only one instance with its name at runtime.